# Is there an automatic way to add a -SNAPSHOT to the pom in branches develop

Tags: git, maven

I have a maven project that has to follow a gitflow approach.

Now, given a release branch what I'd like is that:

- Code merged&push on the develop branch automatically adds -SNAPSHOT to the maven
- Code merged&pushed on the master does not add -SNAPSHOT

Is there some sort of automatic way to attain this via maven plugin+git hooks?